# Clean methods of class based views

Tags: django

Can you confirm that this `def clean()` override does absolutely nothing in the context of a class based view?

```
def clean(self):                      
    cleaned_data = super(UserAddressForm, self).clean()
    address1 = cleaned_data.get('address1')
    address2 = cleaned_data.get('address2')
    city = cleaned_data.get('city')
    state = cleaned_data.get('state')
    city = cleaned_data.get('city')
    state_other = cleaned_data.get('state_other')
    country = cleaned_data.get('country')
    country_other = cleaned_data.get('country_other')
    zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
```

When I was first learning about django, I believed that:
a) this function did something and,
b) This validation was required for a class based view to confirm that the user inputs didn't contain malicious code.

I don't think a) or b) are correct anymore. Can you confirm?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes that doesn't do anything. It just declares variables from `cleaned_data` but does nothing with it. Forms will have clean methods to validate data, and are used by some class based views.

Comment: Yeah I thought `clean` methods only applied in the context of forms and models....

Comment: You don't require to clean everything. It can be used in getting user email or password in the form.

Comment: Thanks everyone!